# injecting a variable value into an anonymous type constructor

Tags: c#, json, anonymous-types

I'm creating an anonymous object to return a json message, as so:

```
return new
{
    response = new
    {
        message = new
        {
            type = "Text",
            text = "blah blah blah"
        }
    }
};
```

I would like to be able to inject a different value for text, ideally by using a variable (myMessage) that gets populated prior to building this anonymous type.

Like this:

```
    message = new
    {
        type = "Text",
        text = myMessage
    }
```

Is that possible?  I've looked all over but can't find a way to do that.

Comment: what happens when you try to use the code ? do you get any errors ..? can you create a generic method to pass in the myMessage string or a method to take in the myMessage string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you very well can do that as in below sample code

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myMessage = "abcd";
        var message = new
        {
            type = "Text",
            text = myMessage
        };

        Console.WriteLine(message.text); //output: abcd
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```